# EDS of BiOCl (Conductivity)

Tags: spectroscopy

For EDS mode of SEM, would you need to create a conductive path to ground for a BiOCl sample material. I have researched and found that gold and carbon can be used for such purposes, but I thought that BiOCl is conductive enough for grounding to occur.

The reason I'm asking this is I was reading a research article, and I came across the following EDS spectra of BiOCl:
[image]

I believe that on the left side "Cl" in purple is mislabelled, as Chlorine only has K-series emission, and the energy of such emission is greater than oxygen, so this led me to believe that the material is has to be smaller than Oxygen, and Carbon seems to be the obvious choice, but the research paper doesn't mention using anything apart BiOCl, and the mount which consists of Al and Cu.

Many Thanks

Comment: Frankly I'd guess that low energy peak labeled Cl is just noise. In a SEM EDS setup the Si(Li) detector needs to be cooled with liquid nitrogen. To prevent an ice buildup the x-rays must pass through a Be window. In order withstand air pressure and prevent slow air/moisture leakage into the detector, the Be window has to be thick enough to seal. Hence no such low energy x-ray is going to pass into the detector. // Note $\ce{Cl K_\alpha}$ escape peak is at 2.622 - 1.74 = 0.882 Kev, about the same energy as the Cu L lines.

Comment: Why are you taking away 1.74 keV from Kalpha of chlorine?

Comment: A $\ce{Cl K_\alpha}$ x-ray enters the $\ce{Si(Li)}$ detector and excites an electron in the $\ce{Si K}$ shell. The Si excited state decays with the emission of an $\ce{Si K\alpha}$ x-ray. The xray sometimes escapes from the detector carrying off 1.74 keV of energy.

Comment: Ok is see. So just 2 more follow up questions: 1. Would this mean that the 1.74 keV electron would also be detected by the detector too (1/2*4pi chance of each such electron not leaving the silicon matrix) 2. Why does the Cu line at roughly 8 keV not have substantial noise at 8-1.74 keV?

Comment: It isn't a 1.74 keV electron, it is a 1.74 keV x-ray. The Cu escape peak would definitely be there. It is just too low in intensity to be visible because the Cu x-rays go deeper into the detector on average making it less likely for the $\ce{Si K\alpha}$ x-ray to escape.